# chain line with narrow-wide chain ring

Tags: mountain-bike, chainline

I'm running a 1 x 10 set up on my mountain bike. Recently I noticed that when I'm on the largest cog, there is a lot of friction in the drive train and is choppy. I think this is due to the fact that the chain line is not aligned with my narrow wide chain ring. Every time a chainlink gets to the wide tooth, it has a bit of trouble getting onto the tooth.

I do not notice this choppiness when I'm in the middle of the cassette and the chain line is straighter. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Did you or a PO convert from another front set of chainrings or is this the factory setup?  If its a conversion, could be the single chainring is too far to the right, and you need a different bottom bracket axle/cartridge to move it left a little.  Do you have any problems in the littlest cog?  Moving the chainring left could cause issues there, where there a fewer teeth.

Comment: @Criggie My bike came with Shimano XT. I wanted a 1x setup so i put a sram x1 crank and chain ring on. I don't have any problems shifting or pedaling, it just makes a lot of noise. I don't recall it making this noise before, but I did recently change my chain.

Answer (score 2):

Change into the middle gear in the cassette and check the chain is straight. Otherwise, you may need to remove a bottom bracket spacer (usually 2.5mm thick) from the drive side and move it to the non-drive side or vice versa. (Of course, make sure the chainring does not contact the chainstay on the frame to avoid damage)

Failing that, you mention in the comments that you changed the chain recently. If your previous chain was very worn, it might be that the chainring is now also worn and might need replacing.